# Can not type most letters on my keyboard into Electron apps

Tags: keyboard, accessibility, electron

All numbers, punctuation, and special characters work normally. I can type normally in all non-Electron apps, but Discord, VSCode and Signal Desktop don't allow me to type anything except "f,w,j,z."

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution.

I noticed that the Screen Reader was enabled (but I didn't enable it). I disabled the Screen Reader in Accessibility settings, and everything works now.